# How to alter a mesh to fit an existing texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I'm not sure how to explain this. I'm trying to alter a mesh for Skyrim and I need the new faces I create to match the existing texture. This is an armor that someone else made and I want to alter the boob plate but when I unwrap the mesh it's in a shape that doesn't match up well with the texture. The only thing I can think to do is push and pull individual vertices, but OMG that is agonizingly tedious. Surely, there's a better way. Here's a screenshot of what I mean. The part of the texture I need to match the UV island with is outlined in red.

[image: Stupidly Can't Do This]

Comment: Do you have access to the original model as well? Or only the texture itself?

Comment: I have the original model. It's the Woodland Priestess Armor mod for Skyrim.

Comment: What you can do is apply the diffuse texture to the original model, align the new model to that, layout the UVs on the new model however you want and then bake the diffuse map from the original to the new, using the original as the "High Poly" mesh, and the new one as the "Low".

Comment: Here's a [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/262895/53513) i made a week or so ago detailing essentially the same process, for a similar situation where another user was modding a car game. It's not identical to your situation, but overall it's about the same process.

Comment: Oh, yeah! I completely forgot baking a new texture from the old is something I could do. Thank you for the reminder. I know how to do that (I have a tutorial for it) but it's been a while since I've done it and I forgot it was possible. Thank you! Thank you!

Comment: There ya go. :)